# Why can't Ruby load a file?

Tags: ruby

I would like to require a file called "factories.rb":

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'factories.rb' )
```

and am getting this error:

```
/home/sean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems
/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- /home/sean/rand/test/factories.rb (LoadError)
```

I have ruby-1.9.3-p194 installed. Why does it also say 1.9.1 in the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, Factory Girl automatically loads the factories.rb file ( and yours is in the right place ).

I often have problems with that require syntax ( it's mostly likely just me ), might try this:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/factories' # it's okay to leave off the .rb
```

Also, the folder is 1.9.1 just 'cause the ruby core team decided to keep the name 1.9.1 throughout the 1.9 release schedule. I'll try and find a link.

EDIT: Here's a link to a previous discussion on SO about the folder being 1.9.1:
[1st answer is good.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564210/why-are-we-installing-ruby-1-9-2-1-9-3-gems-into-a-1-9-1-folder)