# syck : require ssl : different Ruby versions?

Tags: ruby, rake, syck

I'm trying to run a rake task for the railroady gem https://github.com/preston/railroady#readme

In the error message below I think it is referring to Ruby 1.9.1 for syck while I am using Ruby 1.9.3 (see below). Is this normal?

The process is falling over on the following:

```
/Users/sean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load': syntax error on line 62, col 4: `    require_ssl:false ' (ArgumentError)
from /Users/sean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
```

The relevant code from syck.rb is:

```
124     # Load a document from the current _io_ stream.
125     #
126     #   File.open( 'animals.yaml' ) { |yf| YAML::load( yf ) }
127     #      #=> ['badger', 'elephant', 'tiger']
128     #
129     # Can also load from a string.
130     #
131     #   YAML.load( "--- :locked" )
132     #      #=> :locked
133     #
134     def self.load( io )
135         parser.load( io )
136     end
```

Comment: `syntax error on line 62, col 4: \`    require_ssl:false ' ` – I suspect this is an error in one of your yaml config files, not in syck.

Comment: Hey Matt - you might be onto something there! I'll check it out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey Matt. I just ran railroady against another Rails app and it worked fine. Why not post your comment as the answer and I'll accept it. Cheers,
Sean

Comment: Ok, Have done. Also the different version numbers is normal – 1.9.3 uses “1.9.1” as the directory name as it’s “library compatible” (or something like that) with 1.9.1 – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564210/why-are-we-installing-ruby-1-9-2-1-9-3-gems-into-a-1-9-1-folder

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the 1.9.1 question. These rails installs can get a bit tricky, and I was worried I had some crud left over from an older build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message:

```
syntax error on line 62, col 4: `    require_ssl:false '
```

I suspect this is an error in one of your Yaml config files, not in Syck itself – i.e. it’s an error reported *by* Syck, not an error *in* Syck.