# rbenv, ruby 1.9.3-p237 and jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, rbenv

I just replaced RVM with rbenv, and cleaned all RVM-related things.

Everything went fine except Jekyll which doesn't generate anything inside _site.

Then I tried to start it with `--no-auto`, and got this exception:

```
/home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): found unexpected end of stream while scanning a quoted scalar at line 3 column 8 (Psych::SyntaxError)
  from /home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
  from /home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
  from /home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
  from /home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:33:in `read_yaml'
  from /home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/page.rb:24:in `initialize'
  from /home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:140:in `new'
  from /home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:140:in `block in read_directories'
  from /home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:130:in `each'
  from /home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:130:in `read_directories'
  from /home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:98:in `read'
  from /home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:38:in `process'
  from /home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/jekyll:250:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
  from /home/carlos/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

I really have no idea where it got the "1.9.1" inside the gems folder.

`ruby -v`:

```
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-linux]
```

What's going on here?

Comment: The 1.9.1 thing is [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8564210/215168)

Comment: got it, thanks! About the error, any idea?

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like some kind of malformed YAML trying to be parsed. Double-check any .yml config files you have.  The error reads like it's a line that has a string value (starts with a `"`) but the file ends before the matching `"` is found

Comment: not really, I found the issue. Thanks anyway for your help :)

Comment: Psych is the heart of YAML by default in Ruby 1.9, so @AbeVoelker is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. Seems like psych is double loaded, one time by gem, other by stdlib. So, i just removed the gem:

```
 gem uninstall psych
```

And now it's working.

Anyway, here, take some related links:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6520
- https://github.com/CS169-Raxa/raxa-visualizations/issues/51
- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3488
- https://gist.github.com/3079083
- https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/2068
- https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/issues/66

There's also a solution that say's to add the psych gem to application Gemfile. Weird.

Comment: I doubt that "double loaded" has anything to do with it. It's a question of the psych *version*, perhaps. You may have uncovered a bug in the more recent version of psych (the version in the gem). Personally, I'm unhappy about psych being forced upon YAML users in Ruby 1.9; it is not ready for prime time. Previously, Syck was used - and it worked fine.

Comment: maybe... about syck, I agreed with you.

Comment: You can get syck to return by saying `YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'`.

Comment: that's cool! Thanks for your tip.