# Why Do Heroku Stack Traces indicate Ruby 1.9.1 is in use?

Tags: ruby, heroku

Recently saw this stack trace on our Heroku app on cedar

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:156:in `split'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:174:in `parse'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:628:in `parse'
```

**Why is it using Ruby 1.9.1?**

My Gemfile is not specifying a Ruby version.  Heroku's docs suggest that we should be getting the Cedar default of 1.9.2

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

**EDIT:**

ruby -v appears to report the correct version

```
$ heroku run "ruby -v"
Running `ruby -v` attached to terminal... up, run.2594
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: what does `ruby --version` report it will use whatever version you have, generally the `which ruby` version depending on how you start it.

Comment: From an irb session, `RUBY_VERSION => "1.9.2"`

Comment: well irb and ruby are different executables. do you have multiple versions in your path... `whereis ruby`

Comment: Updated the question with the `ruby -v`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not actually using Ruby 1.9.1 -- as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565831/126042) from [Marc-André Lafortune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8279/marc-andre-lafortune) explains, it has to do with the C interface, which hasn't changed since Ruby 1.9.1.

> In Ruby 1.9.0, the C interface was changed from the Ruby 1.8 series.
>
> Gems that compile to native code had to be recompiled.
>
> The interface was again changed in Ruby 1.9.1 and kept the same in Ruby 1.9.2 & 3. This explains the 1.9.1 you are seeing in your path.
>
> The idea is that you can install different versions of Ruby on your system and that gems would be shared within groups having the same C api. So Ruby 1.8.6 and 1.8.7 could share their gems, and so could Ruby 1.9.1, .2 and .3.
>
> It's not necessarily the best idea, though. In any case, most people use rvm to access different versions of Ruby and rvm keeps gems separate for each version, irrespective of the C api version.