# heroku app/vendor/bundle shows wrong version of ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm am getting an error in production that doesn't occur in development.  It appears in the stack trace that the gem is using the wrong version of ruby (2.1.0), but I have specified 2.1.3 in my gemfile and followed the heroku troubleshooting on ruby versions. Based on other stackoverflow information the ruby version makes a difference here. Anyone know how to update app/vendor/bundle to the latest?

This is my error which is occurring in a Resque worker...

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:72:in `block in initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:74:in `yield'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:74:in `block in initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:74:in `yield'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:74:in `block in initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:74:in `yield'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:74:in `block in initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:150:in `yield'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:150:in `accept'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:114:in `push'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych.rb:409:in `dump'
...snip...
```

This is my ruby version...

```
heroku run "ruby --version"
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-linux]
```

This is what's in /app/vendor/bundle...

```
heroku run "ls /app/vendor/bundle/ruby"
2.1.0
```

This is my Gemfile ruby declaration....

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :default do
  # current stable (heroku needs this listed)
  ruby '2.1.3'
  gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
  gem 'redis' # queue mechanism

  gem 'resque', "~> 1.22.0", :require => "resque/server"
  gem 'resque_mailer' # mailer queue
  gem 'resque-scheduler' # job scheduler

  # postgres and database
  gem 'pg' # postgres
  gem 'activerecord-import' # bulk sql insert
  gem 'seed-fu', '~> 2.3' # db seed data

  # APIs
  gem 'bitly'
  gem 'feedjira' # RSS feeds
  gem 'fullcontact'
  gem 'httparty'# rest api client
  gem 'twilio-ruby' # SMS
  gem 'twitter'
  gem 'twitter-text' # convert twitter, links, hashtags and users
  gem 'yahoo-finance', require: 'yahoo_finance'

  # WEB....
  # Use unicorn as the app server
  gem 'unicorn'

  # javascript
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0' # compressor for js assets
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

  # UI/CSS
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  gem 'jqcloud-rails' # word cloud
  gem 'footable-rails' # mobile responsive table
  gem 'font-awesome-sass'# icons
  gem 'highcharts-rails'

  # rails
  gem 'turbolinks'
  gem 'simple_form'

  # admin interface
  gem 'rails_admin' # models admin interface
  gem "psych", "~> 2.0.5" # needed for rails_admin

  # user authentication
  gem 'devise'
  gem 'domp'
  gem 'omniauth'
  gem 'omniauth-twitter'
  gem 'omniauth-stocktwits', :git => 'https://github.com/jesseyoungmann/omniauth-stocktwits.git'

  # app support
  gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.2' # for active model secure password
  gem 'kaminari', :git => 'https://github.com/musicglue/kaminari.git' # pagination
end


# docs
group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end


# test
group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
  gem 'vcr', '~> 2.8.0'
  gem 'webmock', '~> 1.15.0'
end

# development
group :development do
  gem 'foreigner', '~> 1.6.1' # foreign key generator
  gem 'rails_layout'

  # profilers
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
  gem 'ruby-prof'
end

group :production do
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
  gem 'rails_12factor' # heroku
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show your entire gemfile

Comment: I added the whole contents.  I did recently rearrange it, so perhaps I did something dumb.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Do Heroku Stack Traces indicate Ruby 1.9.1 is in use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296990/why-do-heroku-stack-traces-indicate-ruby-1-9-1-is-in-use)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create a `.ruby-version` file in the root of your application and simply put `2.1.3` in it, than your app will always use that version in production and development. I had similar issues in the past and this did the trick for me.

Comment: I've got the .ruby-version file too with **rvm 2.1.3** in it.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of this:

- [Why Do Heroku Stack Traces indicate Ruby 1.9.1 is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296990/why-do-heroku-stack-traces-indicate-ruby-1-9-1-is-in-use)

Same answer as this:

- [Why are we installing Ruby 1.9.2/1.9.3 gems into a 1.9.1 folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564210/why-are-we-installing-ruby-1-9-2-1-9-3-gems-into-a-1-9-1-folder/8565831#8565831)

Comment: Hmmm...that seems like a confusing convention and I guess my problem lies elsewhere.  Thanks.