# How to specify the Ruby version for a Heroku worker (eg. sidekiq)?

Tags: ruby, logging, heroku, version, procfile

I am running `sidekiq` as a Heroku worker as shown in the following `Procfile`:

```
 worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 5 -v
```

I would like for it run on Ruby 1.9.3 instead of 1.9.1 as shown when running `heroku logs -t`. I have specified `ruby "1.9.3"` in the `Gemfile`and it even shows this when I run `git push heroku master`:

```
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
```

Both the `web` and `worker` dynos appear to be running 1.9.1 according to `heroku logs`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing to worry about. Bundler stores the gems in 1.9.1 for ruby 1.9.3. For more info, see here: [Why are we installing Ruby 1.9.2/1.9.3 gems into a 1.9.1 folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564210/why-are-we-installing-ruby-1-9-2-1-9-3-gems-into-a-1-9-1-folder)