# Ruby bundle creating a self contained package

Tags: ruby, deployment, installation, package, bundler

My objective is:
Create a self contained tar.gz of a ruby app (graylog2-web-client) that I can install and run on a box with *no internet connection* and only ruby 1.9.3 installed (rvm, bundler, etc. will not be available).

I have installed and launched the app correctly, now I wish to package it and move it to the target box.

Update to question:

I used bundle install --development to ensure that all gems are in the vendor/cache.
I tared the package and moved it to new box. 
I have updated my path so that my 1.9.3 ruby install comes before the default 1.8.x.

```
ruby --version 
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux]
```

However when I run  `RAILS_ENV=production script/rails server`

I get require/dependency errors:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/graylog2-web-interface-0.11.0/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

My vender dir:

```
├── bundle
│   └── ruby
│       └── 1.9.1
├── cache
│   ├── actionmailer-3.2.13.gem
│   ├── actionpack-3.2.13.gem
│   ├── activemodel-3.2.13.gem
     ...... lots more gems.......
```

I bundled this under 1.9.3 why is my bundle showing 1.9.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gems installed under 1.9.3 go into a 1.9.1 directory because they have the same compatibility version. This is normal Ruby Gems behavior, see [Why are we installing Ruby 1.9.2/1.9.3 gems into a 1.9.1 folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564210/why-are-we-installing-ruby-1-9-2-1-9-3-gems-into-a-1-9-1-folder)

All of your gems should be installed into the `bundle/ruby/1.9.1` directory. Do you see them in there?

To run on a server without bundler installed, you'll need to generate the tarball using `bundle install --standalone`.

This creates a file at `bundle/bundler/setup.rb` that you can require from `config/boot.rb` instead of requiring `bundler/setup`.

See: http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/03/faster-test-boot-times-with-bundler-standalone

Comment: yes, my gems are present in the 1.9.1 dir. I have run bundle install --standalone, and pointed config/boot.rb to bundle/bundler/setup. Still not working. Clearly, I have missed something.

Comment: marked you correct. Thanks for your help. I ended up shipping the bundler gem with my package as well as all the gems in the cache, I then installed it and was able to run bundle install --local.

Comment: I'm curious to see why standalone didn't work for you. One thing I forgot to note, depending on the app you might need to use `require_relative` to help it find `bundle/bundler/setup` or otherwise to manipulate the load path to make sure it includes the app directory.