# How to get the Ruby compatible lib version from command line or program?

Tags: ruby

As I know,

```
ruby -e 'puts RUBY_VERSION'
```

will print out ruby version. In Ubuntu 14.04, they will print

```
1.9.3
```

but its libraries path is

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1
```

- Why are they different?
- How can I get the latter one?

Comment: Near-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8565831/125816

Comment: The title does not match the questions.

Comment: If you were able to get the latter one (library path), why are you asking how to get it?

Comment: I want to get it from command line or program.

Answer (score 2):

- Why are they different?

  Because compatible Ruby versions (often (but not always) within the same major version) share the libraries. Ruby 1.9.3 share the libraries with 1.9.1.
- How can I get the latter one?

  ```
  $LOAD_PATH
  ```

  or

  ```
  Gem.default_path
  ```

Comment: Is there any way to get the compatible version directly, just like 1.9.1?